# img not displaying on Android

Tags: android, html, android-9.0-pie

I have a simple image in my html which renders fine on my PC, but not on my smartphone:

```
<div id="welcomebox">
        <img src="geschenk.jpg"/>      
</div>
```

my folder-structure is as follows:

```
C:/Maus
  - index.html
  - geschenk.jpg
```

on my smartphone I copy that folder to my download-folder and open index.html from there. There's no web-server included, I directly open the file from the filesystem.

[image]

But on my smartphone the image isn't displayed.

Comment: How do you open a html file? Which app do you use for it?  And in which app the html is displayed?

Comment: @blackapps I open it with chrome for android.

Comment: Where does Chrome have a menu item like "Open file"?

Comment: @blackapps It doesn't, however the filesystem has the "open-with"-item

Comment: Please be exact!!! In my first comment i already asked which app you/the user used to select the html file. You should name an app. File systems is something different.

Comment: @blackapps this is done using the files-app

Comment: And then the user chooses Chrome to display the image. You have any idea with which data the Files (not files) app starts Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will receive a content scheme from the Files app like:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file:// ...../index.html
```

As soon as Chrome 'sees' a content scheme it cannot display pictures as even if Chrome changes the scheme to:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file:// ...../geschenk.jpg
```

the provider will not let it access as there is no read permission for it.

Comment: so there's no way to display the image except creating a webservice on any server and upload the files there?

Comment: Yes that is possible. And you could use your own provider to serve html and pictures. But i understand you are not programming an Android app at the moment.

Comment: You can also install a webserver app on you phone.

Answer (score 0):

The Android filesystem structure can't open relative file paths the same way other systems do.
So the answer is you need to use a complete hardcoded `file:///` path.

This is not a very good approach since you need to replace all the URLs/paths in your HTML files.

Another approach if you are determined to do so, you can upload all project resources such as images, CSS, javascript to the cloud, like using SDN to access those files and to let the project work. But using the SDN approach it's easier to upload everything including the HTML files to a hosting account.

Comment: `The Android filesystem structure can't open relative file paths the same way other systems do. ` This has nothing to do with file systems but with apps that can handle relative paths. Well Chrome can.